# My Java Spring Boot Maven REST API doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm starting in Java J2E and I'm following [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-spring-boot-rest-api-a-php-developers-view-part-i-6add2e794646) tutorial to develop a REST API with Java, Spring Boot and Maven.

I don't understand the following error, someone please explain to me?.... :/
My code: https://github.com/AngierRomain/API-REST-Spring-Java-Maven

The error is in the ERROR.txt file

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the minimal code to the post (see [mcve] such that people can clearly understand. See [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you have added the dependency in your pom :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You have also created a `Repository` class. I am assuming that you want to use Postgres Db to fetch/store the Blog details.

On running this spring application, getting this error

```java
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

This is because you are trying to use data-Jpa( pom dependency) and also postgres (dependency is  present in pom) but you haven't provided the dialect and connection details in your application.properties.

Add this in application.properties

```java
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/blog
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Now, getting this error from entity manager :

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class me.romain.Blog
```

In your repository class, your Entity class has been specified as `Blog.java`

```java
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Integer>
```

If you see your `Blog` class, it is a plain POJO class. It is not DTO. DTO is responsible for interacting with the database. To make a POJO an entity class you have to specify it.

You can do this using `Entity` and `Id` annotation of `javax.persistence` package

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Blog {

    @Id
    private int id;
}
```

Now, that you have followed all this and all the data source connection details are right, I think it should work for you.

Note: You should try saving some sample data in DB and fetch it from there to check if it really works.

---

If you want just your current code to work, 
Remove Repository class, remove the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency from pom. And you should be able to run your application.